# PHP Remove spaces and %20 within single function

Tags: php, regex

I wish to remove white space from a string. The string would have ben `urlencoded()` prior, so I also wish to remove `%20` too. I can do this using two separate functions, but how do i do this with one function?

```
$string = str_replace("%20","",$string);
$string = str_replace(" ","",$string);
```

Comment: `|` or ? ???????????????

Comment: `$string = str_replace(["%20"," "],"",$string);` RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Steve thanks for the reply but, this throws an error `<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' on line <b>3</b><br />`

Comment: @user3770579 what PHP version are you using? Steve's way is a shorthand array.

Comment: why not just do vice versa - str_replace(' ', '', urldecode(someString)) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
preg_replace('~%20| ~', "", $string)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried something very similar to this. What does the `~` mean in your example please?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for that but strtr:

```
$result = strtr($str, array('%20'=>'', ' '=>''));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realise I could use an array within `strtr`

Comment: @user3770579: Yes, there are indeed two syntaxes, The main advantage of strtr (except the incredible speed) is that the string is parsed only once (unlike str_replace).